# How to put answer into a vector?

Tags: r

How to put answer into a vector?
Here is example :

```
for(i in 1:5){
n=0
k=2
while(k<100){
n=n+1
k=k+2}
print(n)}
```

The answers are all 49 ,my question is how to put the answer into a vector.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a `null vector` say `v` beforehand and enter every ith iteration of n into v[i]

```
#create a null vector v
v <- NULL
#your loop
for(i in 1:5){
  n=0
  k=2
  while(k<100){
    n=n+1
    k=k+2}
  v[i] <- n
  print(n)}
[1] 49
[1] 49
[1] 49
[1] 49
[1] 49

 v
[1] 49 49 49 49 49
```

#OR without printing

```
v <- NULL
for(i in 1:5){
  n=0
  k=2
  while(k<100){
    n=n+1
    k=k+2}
  v[i] <- n
  }
v
[1] 49 49 49 49 49
```